# Rendering email with HTML/CSS in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching an email from gmail and grabbed the html with CSS markup. I'd like to render it in a React app, but react is interpreting it as a string vs html.

How do I tell react to render the HTML/CSS?

```
var AnotherComponent = React.crateClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.html_email}</div>
    )
  }
})

var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <AnotherComponent html_email = {this.props.html_body} />
    )
  }
})
```

In this case, `html_body` is

```
<div><p style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" data-mce-style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-family: Arial; color: #222222; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;" data-mce-style="font-family: Arial; color: #222222; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">SOME TEXT</span></p><br><p style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" data-mce-style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-family: Arial; color: #222222; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;" data-mce-style="font-family: Arial; color: #222222; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">
```

It is showing all of the html as a string vs just `SOME TEXT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does because you pass it like this. If you really need to do it, you should do:

```
var AnotherComponent = React.crateClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html_email}}</div>
    )
  }
})
```

But you shouldn't. From docs:

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it's easy to
>   inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack

[read more](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: ahh, ok. This is just an internal application im just running on my local host to generate reports :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @Piotr's solution you can parse the HTML and render it on your own. You should only render subset of valid tags in order to prevent nasty XSS attacks.

You can also use some existing solutions like [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser) or other HTML parsers.